# .htaccess rewrite rule not reading the last two parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this rules in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^clothes/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ products.php?g=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11 [L]
RewriteRule ^clothes/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ products.php?g=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9 [L]
RewriteRule ^clothes/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ products.php?g=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7 [L]
RewriteRule ^clothes/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ products.php?g=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^clothes/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ products.php?g=$1&$2=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^clothes/([^/]+)/?$ products.php?g=$1 [L]
```

which can be something like `website.com/clothes/women/type/tshirts/brand/nike/color/red/size/s/price/0-29`
and this should be the `print_r($_GET)`

```
Array
(
    [g] => women
    [type] => tshirts
    [color] => red
    [brand] => nike
    [size] => s
    [prezzo] => 0-29
)
```

So starting from `website.com/clothes/women/` I can then add filter/value pairs and arrive at the point where I can have that big url with all the possible filters.

The problem is that the last filter/value pair is not working, this snippet from the first rule in .htaccess `[..]&$10=$11`. So instead of the aspected dumped data, I get this

```
Array
(
    [g] => women
    [type] => tshirts
    [color] => red
    [brand] => nike
    [size] => s
    [women0] => women1
)
```

So basically it replaces the last filter/value pair with the name of the first filter, `g=$1`.

Is there a limit withing .htaccess of how many parameters I can pass into the `url` ? It seems to me that the last parameter is `$9`, so `$10` is not taken into consideration.

If that is the case, can I fix this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can only use `$0 to $9` captured groups.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I figured.

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this `mod_rewrite` by having this recursive rule. Place this in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(clothes/[^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ $1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^clothes/([^/]+)/?$ products.php?g=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I don't really know how this would behave, and I can't test it now, but would the result be the same ? Care to explain ? Thank you.

Comment: This is for solving the problem you are running into i.e. more than 9 captured groups. It solves it by repeated execution of same rewrite rule. Test it out and let me know. If it works I can add more detailed explanation.